# { message = "The request is invalid."; modelState = { model = ( "An error has occurred." ); }; } occurred error when I used Put Request of Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, put

I am creating an Event app where in the user should tap **Check In Button** to register for the event. `registered_flag : false` will be `true`  and  `registered_type: 0` will be 1 once the user tapped the button. But as I build and run the app, error appeared that says [console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KGmb.png) . and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UAnB.png) is the postman response when I checked it.

I am not really confident regarding the content of my codes in my APIService. Hope someone will help me to correct my codes so I could build and run my app successfully. Thank you so much.

**APIService**

```
func updateParticipant(updateType: UpdateParticipantType,
                       participantID: String,
                       completionHandler: @escaping((String?, Error?) -> Void)) {

    let updateParticipantURL = URL(string: "\(REGISTER_PARTICIPANT_URL)/\(participantID)")

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json"
    ]

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "registered_flag": "false",
        "registration_type": 0
    ]

    Alamofire.request(updateParticipantURL!, method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)

        switch response.result {
        case .success:
           /// print("Done")

            if let jsonArray = response.result.value {
                print("jsonArray\(jsonArray)")
               // let success = Attendee.init(JSON: jsonArray as! [String : Any])
               //  completionHandler(success, nil)

            }

        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
  }
 }
```

**JSON to be updated**

```
{
"registered_flag" : "true",
"registration_type" : 1
}
```

**This will be the result when JSON once updated**

```
 [
    {
    "participant_id": "e861e807-86af-454f-87e9-8b4a0832cee3",
    "employee_number": null,
    "last_name": "Aguilar",
    "first_name": "Dia",
    "middle_name": null,
    "registered_flag": true,
    "registered_datetime": "2018-09-18T13:55:33.613",
    "registration_type": 1
    }
 ]
```

Comment: In your current code you wrote `"registration_type" : 0` instead of `"registration_type" : 1`. Is that a typo? Side note, avoid using `!` (force unwrap), prefers `if let` or `guard let`.

Comment: @Larme In my json the default value of `"registration_type": 0` then once the user clicks the button to check in the `"registration_type"` will be `1`. I am really confuse on how I will construct it. I am new in swift

Comment: I suggest that you add `.validate()` (i.e. `Alamofire.request(...).validate().responseJSON { ... }`) this will cause the response to actually return an error if the HTTP response code returns an error, and it should make it easier to debug.

Comment: @GuyKogus Hi I tried to insert `validate()`. It shows `responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(400))` How can I solve it?

Comment: You should investigate what you're getting back in the response data. I use an extension for `Data` that I mainly just use while debugging: `extension Data { func jsonObject(options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = [.allowFragments]) throws -> Any {
    return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self, options: options)
}
}`
put a breakpoint in the completion closure and check what the data converts to.